# iScroll - Preserving native vertical scroll - works in iOS, not Android

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I'm using iScroll.js to scroll through a carousel of items on a mobile page. I found the following fix that listens for vertical movement and stops the iScroll script taking control, letting the native vertical scroll happen:

```
        onBeforeScrollStart: function(e) {
        try {
            point = e.touches[0];
            pointStartX = point.pageX;
            pointStartY = point.pageY;
        } catch(e) {}
        null;
    },
    onBeforeScrollMove: function(e) {
        try {
            deltaX = Math.abs(point.pageX - pointStartX);
            deltaY = Math.abs(point.pageY - pointStartY);
            if (deltaX >= deltaY) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                null;
            }
        } catch(e) {}
    }
```

I'm using try{}catch{} as it had some issues when testing in a browser (complained about point not being defined).

The issue I'm having is that it works well on iOS, tested on several i-devices, but on Android it's not so good. If a user tries to scroll the page vertically, starting by placing the finger on the carousel, the page doesn't scroll as the iScroll still has control.

Any idea how I can get it to work on Android, or any pointers toward where it might be going wrong?

Edit:

Some debugging and I've discovered possibly why this isn't working. The coordinates are being updated while the user touches the screen on iOS, but on Android, only the first set of coordinates are being caught. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Have you tried using `myScroll.disable()` and `myScroll.enable()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have "point" in your scope for onBeforeScrollMove.
Also, some Android devices may invoke click events over multitouch (I cannot confirm this, but only theorize because of platform fragmentation)

I've got a nice script that I'll be releasing soon that takes click events and simulates a unique multitouch event using "mouse" as the identifier property of the touch, that might be of some help w/ debugging.  I'll try to have the project up online by tomorrow night.

It's due for a number of updates and projects to be added, but here's a link:

https://github.com/skhameneh

EDIT: Correction, are you even updating "point"?  It seems to be scoped outside of this piece of code and changed within.  Might be helpful if you posted the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of iScroll actually has a port that seems to work exactly as you describe by paging horizontally and still allowing vertical scrolling. https://github.com/cubiq/2-way-iScroll